# Debian 8.0 Jessie:MAKE .o file not recognized

Tags: object, makefile, debian-jessie

I am new to coding, however I have developed a PoW minable cryptocurrency with working Linux command line wallet, however when using the gitian-descriptors build scripts (github.com/gurtaj-project/gurtaj.git)

I am trying to link Linux to Windows and create a Windows .exe QT via build-script(Gitian-win32.yml)however I come across the error of .o files, object files not being recognized by the ld when i cat into the build.log

Please go easy on me and explain in simple terms why the build-script is crashing because of this, I will attach screenshot for more clear details.

Here is the build script with clearly identified dependencies and required files: https://github.com/gurtaj-project/gurtaj/blob/v0.8/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-win32.yml

Compiling error in `gitian-descriptors/var/cat build.log`

```
./build/version.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [release/gurtaj-qt.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/build/gurtaj'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Comment: "*I am new to coding, however I have developed a PoW minable cryptocurrency*" <- that's ... improbable. "*I am trying to link Linux to Windows*" <- huh?

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... right now, it's not possible to understand your problem.